# Fechar modal bootstrap automaticamente quando enviar formulário

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, modal

Tenho um modal do bootstrap cujo o mesmo possui um formulário para contato:

**HTML:**

**Obrigado!** Seu formulário foi enviado com sucesso e assim que possível será respondido.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="contactModalLabel">Formulário para contato</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <form method="POST" id="ajax_form" action="sendForm.php">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Seu nome:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Escreva seu nome">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Seu email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="seunome@seudominio.com.br">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Assunto:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Escreva o assunto da mensagem">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Mensagem:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="mensagem" name="message" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"></textarea>
                              </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar mensagem">
                             </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS:**

```js
$('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
      var dados = $( this ).serialize();

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendForm.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data)
        {
          $("#msg").attr({"style":"display: block;"});
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

  $("#closeModal").on("click", function(){

   $("#msg").attr({"style":"display: none;"});
```

Até aqui está tudo certo, o modal abre corretamente, o formulário é exibido e quando eu envio o formulário, o alerta de obrigado aparece na tela.
Porém, eu gostaria de uma função que, assim que eu enviar o formulário, o modal fechasse automaticamente, pois o alerta aparece mas ainda fica em segundo plano, com o modal sendo destacado...

Aproveitando o post, gostaria de perguntar também o por que do alerta demorar **(cerca de 10 segundos)** para aparecer na tela. Será que é porque estou usando ajax em localhost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar o `modal('hide')`.

```
$('#seu_modal').modal('hide');
```

Isso pode ser executado dentro do `success`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('.abrir').on('click', function(){

  $('.modal').modal('show');  
  
});

$('.fechar').on('click', function(){

  $('.modal').modal('hide'); 

});

$('form').on('submit', function(){

  $('.modal').modal('hide'); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><button class="abrir"> Abrir </button><div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactModalLabel"> <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> <h4 class="modal-title" id="contactModalLabel">Formulário para contato</h4> </div><div class="modal-body"> <form> <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">Seu nome:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Escreva seu nome"> </div><div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">Seu email:</label> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="seunome@seudominio.com.br"> </div><div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">Assunto:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Escreva o assunto da mensagem"> </div><div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">Mensagem:</label> <textarea class="form-control" id="mensagem" name="message" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"></textarea> </div></div><div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default fechar" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary fechar" value="Enviar mensagem"> </form> </div></div></div></div>
```

> A redundância de `click` e `submit` é devido à pre-visualização do StackOverflow as vezes não permitir enviar o formulário, mas isso é só uma demonstração.

Comment: Aah obrigado, deu certo :) 
Aproveitando, você teria uma resposta pra minha segunda pergunta?
"... gostaria de perguntar também o por que do alerta demorar (cerca de 10 segundos) para aparecer na tela. Será que é porque estou usando ajax em localhost?"

Comment: Isso não me parece um problema. O modal somente irá aparecer depois do JS ser carregado, é necessário que o Jquery e o Bootstrap estejam carregados para aparecer. Exceto se definir no CSS, assim quando o CSS for carregado já estará aberto, mesmo que sem o JS.

Comment: Não, não... O problema não tá no modal... Ao clicar em "Enviar mensagem" dentro do modal, ele demora cerca de 10 segundos para sair da tela (com o código hide que me passou) e o alerta de mensagem enviada só aparece depois desse tempo também, ou seja, o JS demora pra atualizar as informações que foram definidas (o alerta aparecer e o modal esconder)... Isso estaria acontecendo porque estou usando ajax em localhost? É porque eu não gostaria dessa demora quando eu passar o site pra hospedagem

Comment: O problema então está no tempo de resposta. O "servidor" está demorando para responder. Por exemplo, se estiver usando PHP é ele quem está demorando para devolver a informação ao ajax. O `success` é feito imediatamente após obter a resposta do servidor.

Comment: Ah entendi... Sim, estou usando PHP, teria algum jeito d'eu acelerar o tempo de resposta? Porque o meu código está simples, veja: http://prntscr.com/duya2n

Comment: O `mail()` é quem consome o tempo, tem um tópico sobre isso em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325269/what-makes-phps-mail-function-so-slow (em inglês). No servidor isso pode ser melhor do que como está no localhost, obviamente.

Comment: Ah certo, obrigado por esclarecer todas as minhas dúvidas e me ajudar :)

Comment: @GabrielMoodlight, marque a resposta. Não abandone a pergunta ;)

Answer (score -4):

parent.$('#meumodal').modal('hide');

Answer (score -4):

Comigo funcionou desta forma:

```
jQuery('#modal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Olá Augusto Lima, além de responder a pergunta apenas com código, você poderia explicá-lo e mostrar como ele solucionaria o problema do Gabriel?