# Fechar modal ao enviar meu formulário

Tags: javascript

Tenho um modal para enviar formulário, quando eu clico em salvar deveria aparecer uma mensagem dizendo que o usuário foi cadastrado com sucesso e fechar o modal, porém nenhum dos dois está acontecendo.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#formNovo').validate({
  rules: {
    Nome: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },

    Email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },

  messages: {
    txtNome: "Um nome e necessario e com mais de três letras",
    txtEmail: "Insira um endereço de E-mail válido"
  },

  submitHandler: function(formNovo) {
    var usuario = {
      Nome: $("#Nome").val(),
      Email: $("#Email").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: "/Usuario/Adicionar",
      cache: false,
      data: new FormData(document.getElementById("formNovo")),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      method: "POST",
      success: function(dados) {
        $("#divAlert").text("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!")[0].className = "alert alert-success";

        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#divAlert').text("")[0].className = "hidden";

        }, 1000);

        document.getElementById('Nome').value = '';
        document.getElementById('Email').value = '';
        $("#modalNovo").modal('hide');
        atualizarGrid();
      },

      error: function() {
        $("#divAlert").text("Erro ao realizar o cadastro...")[0].className = "alert alert-danger";
      }
    });
  }
});

</script>
```

```html
<div id="modalNovo" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form class="container-fluid" id="formNovo">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Novo cadastro</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Nome">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nome" name="Nome" maxlength="30" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="email@email.com" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnSalvar">Salvar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fechar modal bootstrap automaticamente quando enviar formulário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177154/fechar-modal-bootstrap-automaticamente-quando-enviar-formul%c3%a1rio)

Comment: Mas o formulário está sendo enviado e o cadastro efetuado?

Comment: Sim, o formulário estava sendo enviado. De qualquer forma a solução Lucas Aryosa funcionou. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar os atributos no botão de submite `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNovo"` conforme código abaixo.

```
<div id="modalNovo" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form class="container-fluid" id="formNovo">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Novo cadastro</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Nome">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nome" name="Nome" maxlength="30" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="email@email.com" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnSalvar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNovo">Salvar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou você pode usar a função do bootstrap através do jQuery `$('#modalNovo').modal('hide')` como o código abaixo:

```
submitHandler: function(formNovo) {
    var usuario = {
      Nome: $("#Nome").val(),
      Email: $("#Email").val()
    };

    $('#modalNovo').modal('hide'); //add essa linha

    $.ajax({
      url: "/Usuario/Adicionar",
      cache: false,
      data: new FormData(document.getElementById("formNovo")),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      method: "POST",
      success: function(dados) {
        $("#divAlert").text("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!")[0].className = "alert alert-success";

        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#divAlert').text("")[0].className = "hidden";

        }, 1000);

        document.getElementById('Nome').value = '';
        document.getElementById('Email').value = '';
        $("#modalNovo").modal('hide');
        atualizarGrid();
      },

      error: function() {
        $("#divAlert").text("Erro ao realizar o cadastro...")[0].className = "alert alert-danger";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.